# Are Solars unkillable in a dead magic area or anti-magic field?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, antimagic-field, regeneration

Solars have the regeneration special ability only to take lethal damage from evil epic weapons.

And it seems epic weapons are still subject to the dead magic area and the anti-magic field's effects. That is, they become normal masterwork non-magical weapons there.

So if a Solar stays in a dead magic area or casts an anti-magic field, would those effects protect him from both spells and physical attacks, which makes him unkillable?

UPDATE: I know Epic Spells have a chance to pass anti-magic field, so they are not in the consideration.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah probably that would be a clearer term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes, this should work

Regeneration in general says:

> Damage dealt to the creature is treated as nonlethal damage, and the creature automatically cures itself of nonlethal damage at a fixed rate per round, as given in the creature’s entry.

And the exception for the Solar's regeneration is

> A solar takes normal damage from epic evil-aligned weapons, and from spells or effects with the evil descriptor.

Alignment for weapons is a [magical property](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicWeapons.htm) of the weapon, and if the magic properties are suppressed by Antimagic Field, they won't work. Likewise, magical effects and spells will be suppressed in the field.

---

**P.S.** I originally thought that an inherently evil creature could work. However the rules for these are:

> A creature with an alignment subtype (chaotic, evil, good, or lawful) **can overcome this type of damage reduction** with its natural weapons and weapons it wields as if the weapons or natural weapons had an alignment (or alignments) that match the subtype(s) of the creature.

So, rules as written, these creatures only overcome **damage reduction** effects, and what's protecting the Planetar here is **regeneration**, not damage reduction. (Of course, a DM can rule it also applies to regeneration, but then, a DM can rule whatever they want).

**P.S.S.** While it is unkillable by damage while in the field, that does not mean you cannot kill it. The solar will still be unconscious when at 0 hit points. You could keep pummeling it to keep it K.O., drag it out of the antimagic field or dead magic zone, and kill it there. Suffocating it (see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/206901/75095)) also would work, even in the field.

Comment: As a side comment, you still can knock out the solar, and while it is KO, drag it out of the antimagic field, and finish it off there.

Comment: It's true that Unholy is a magical property of a weapon, but the Evil subtype makes everything you use evil-aligned, and that doesn't... seem to be magical. Can you show that the Evil subtype's effect is magical?

Comment: Maybe it's something about the Epic part, but I find it even harder to believe that an Atropal's epic-natural-weapon-ness is nullified in an AMF.

Comment: @Phoenices I was looking at that (I really thought there ought to be something that beats this), but all the alignments are listed in the same magic item section as other stuff. There is a section on evil critters nat weapon being evil but only in relation to resistance, not for regeneration. Also nearly fell into the trap DaleM did, but saw the exception on that in time.

Comment: I don't see what you mean.... the Unholy weapon type is listed in the magic item section, and it has a side-effect of making your weapon evil-aligned, but "evil-aligned weapons" aren't listed in the magic item section. It seems you're saying that rings of energy resistance are listed under magic items -> energy resistance is nullified by an AMF (and I know that's ridiculous, so clearly I misunderstand). But evil-aligned is just a property of Unholy weapons and a lot of other things.

Comment: Oh, I see the second part of what you said. That it... only... explicitly breaks DR as if evil-aligned, and not regeneration. That can't be intended... but fair enough, maybe add that as a caveat to your answer? I don't think most DMs would say that an epic demon cannot kill a Solar because they only overcome DR, not regeneration.

Comment: @Phoenices I added it in. I had it in my original draft, but took it out to keep it more concise

Answer (score 5):

### Drowning

Fill a large pit with water. Attack the solar for nonlethal damage until it is unconscious. Continue beating it while you throw it into the water.

As long as you can keep it unconscious it will begin to make con checks after 40 rounds and drown.

Comment: Just realise outsiders still need to breath LOL

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to kill a solar in an *antimagic field*:

- **Trollbane**. This is an alchemical substance from *Dungeonscape* that, for a mere 90 gp, allows a weapon to ignore regeneration for a single hit. Since the solar has helpfully suppressed all its buffs, all it has is a 35 AC and 209 hit points, neither of which are impressive for a CR 23 monster. Importantly, a charging PC won't need to enter the *antimagic field* to hit the solar, so the party will have all their magical buffs up while the solar won't.
- **Conjuration**. *Antimagic field* explicitly doesn't do anything about instantaneous conjuration spells, and it just so happens that the best blasting spells in the game, the Orb of X line from *Spell Compendium*, are instantaneous conjurations. Any blaster sorcerer or wizard is probably already using these spells, and just needs to make them evil somehow. There are many options here, from the Corrupt Spell feat from *Book of Vile Darkness*, Debilitating Spell or Tainted Scholar from *Heroes of Horror,* or even the Aligned Spellcaster feature from Dragon 357. (Or, more likely, the blaster will just blast the solar into unconsciousness and then drag it out of the *antimagic field* to kill it.)
- **Ignoring the *antimagic field***. The cleanest options for this are the Initiate of Mystra feat, from *Player's Guide to Faerûn*, or the spell *invoke magic*, from *Lords of Madness*. Once you can ignore the *antimagic field*, you can either use evil blasting spells or the spell *graymantle*, from the *Spell Compendium*, which suppresses regeneration.
- **Nonmagical poison**. Regeneration only affects hit point damage, and solars aren't immune to poison. They'll role 1s on their fortitude saves eventually.

The solar is a CR 23 monster, and most of that challenge comes from the fact that it's a 20th level cleric, not its raw stats. A solar isn't scary because it can attack for 3d6+18 damage four times a round, it's scary because it knew this fight was coming from its casting of *divination* last night and is buffed to the gills, and can open combat with *wish* and *miracle*. In an antimagic field, its just a sitting duck. It'll probably get knocked unconscious before it can act and dragged out of the *antimagic field*, but even if the fight occurs in a massive dead magic zone, the solar is still perfectly killable through its regeneration.

Comment: Trollbane, Graymantle and poison seem to work because they ignore regeneration, but the other options don't by default handle the epic part of the DR, right?

Comment: "A solar takes normal damage from epic evil-aligned weapons, and from spells or effects with the evil descriptor." The spells don't need to be epic, they just need to be evil, which is much easier to do. A *corrupted orb of force*, for example, can kill a solar through an *antimagic field.*

Comment: +1. These are all good methods to get around it, but especially for your last paragraph that instead of just listing mechanics, explains shy this is not a good idea for the solar

Answer (score -3):

### No

> As a full-round action, you can use a melee weapon to deliver a coup de grace to a helpless opponent. You can also use a bow or crossbow, provided you are adjacent to the target.
>
> You automatically hit and score a critical hit. If the defender survives the damage, he must make a Fortitude save (DC 10 + damage dealt) or die.

Do enough non lethal damage to render them unconscious and the coup de gras them until they die.

Comment: "If the attack used to deliver a coup de grace is of a type that regeneration converts to nonlethal damage, the coup de grace fails to kill the regenerating creature" (*RC* 74).